# How to add invoice to Quickbooks using their API with Python?

Tags: python, api, quickbooks

I wonder how can I add an invoice via Quickbooks API v3 using Python. A script with minimum requirements would be appreciated.

I am new to APIs so, I am interested if I can write a simple script without running server to upload invoices to QuickBooks. If not, I guess I should use Django or Flask right?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple example of how to create a single-line Invoice with only required fields.

```
from quickbooks.objects import (Invoice, 
                                SalesItemLineDetail, 
                                SalesItemLine)

customer_ref = Ref()
customer_ref.value = 123
customer_ref.name = 'Ivan Petrov'
customer_ref.type = 'Customer'
# or customer_ref = Customer.get(123, qb=client).to_ref()

line_detail = SalesItemLineDetail()
line_detail.UnitPrice = 100  # in dollars
line_detail.Qty = 1  # quantity can be decimal

line = SalesItemLine()
line.Amount = 100  # in dollars
line.SalesItemLineDetail = line_detail

invoice = Invoice()
invoice.CustomerRef = customer_ref
invoice.Line = [line]

client = QuickBooks(...)

invoice.save(qb=client)
```

follow this link for more explanation [www.github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks/issues/103](http://www.github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks/issues/103)

Answer (score 2):

For invoice, you must have a customer who will pay, accounts for expense and income, and item of service or product that provide to the customer.

```
# client is your quickbook object
customer = Customer()
customer.CompanyName = "Test221wq Company"
customer.DisplayName = "Test3wrq1 Owner"
customer.PrimaryEmailAddr = EmailAddress()
customer.PrimaryEmailAddr.Address = "test1wq3@email.com"
customer.save(qb=client)
print(customer.__dict__)

income_account = Account()
income_account.Name = "Test3w1 Account"
income_account.AccountSubType = "ServiceFeeIncome"
income_account.CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts = 500
income_account.save(qb=client)
print(income_account.__dict__)

expense_account = Account()
expense_account.Name = "Test4 Account"
expense_account.AccountSubType = "CostOfLabor"
expense_account.CurrentBalanceWithSubAccounts = 1000
expense_account.save(qb=client)
print(expense_account.__dict__)


item = Item()
item.Name = "Test Service Item"
item.IncomeAccountRef = income_account.to_ref()
item.ItemCategoryType = "Service"
item.ExpenseAccountRef = expense_account.to_ref()
item.Type = "Service"
item.save(qb=client)
print(item.__dict__)


line = SalesItemLine()
line.LineNum = 1
line.Description = "fieldworkers"
line.Amount = 100
line.SalesItemLineDetail = SalesItemLineDetail()
line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef = item.to_ref()


invoice = Invoice()
invoice.CustomerRef = customer.to_ref()
invoice.Line.append(line)

invoice.save(qb=client)

print(invoice.__dict__)
```

This is enough to generate an invoice.

Comment: This worked for me when the other solutions here didn't. Also to send the invoice in the end, I used the invoice.send(qb=qb_client, send_to="aaaaaa@gmail.com") in the linked GitHub issue, on one of the other solutions to send the invoice email, which worked.

Worth noting that this same GitHub Issue said you need to modify your local instalation of the Python quickbooks library but this doesn't seem to be the case any more (or at least wasn't the case for me) so this may have been fixed upsteam now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [python-quickbooks](https://github.com/ej2/python-quickbooks) library.

There are also examples how to use it:

```py
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from quickbooks import QuickBooks

auth_client = AuthClient(
    client_id='CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET',
    environment='sandbox',
    redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/callback',
)

client = QuickBooks(
    auth_client=auth_client,
    refresh_token='REFRESH_TOKEN',
    company_id='COMPANY_ID',
)

customer = Customer()
customer.CompanyName = "Test Company"
customer.save(qb=client)
```

Comment: @lasha-dolenjashvili have you tried to use this example?

Comment: where to get the refresh token and company id?

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan when you complete OAuth flow, you'll get a `auth_code` which should be converted to these tokens (method `get_bearer_token()`) and save for later use.

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan looks like it is not related to current question, please create a new one and feel free to send a link.